# php notice undefined index http_host in $GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS']['HTTP_HOST']

Tags: php, http, host

Suddenly, I'm getting this notice from php after a recent php version update.  It is used in several places (particularly my htmlMimeMail class).

Code is: `$mail->setSMTPParams('*mail.xxxx.xxx*', 26, $GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS']['HTTP_HOST'], 1, '*email-name*', '*email-password*');`

The notice is:    `Undefined index:  HTTP_HOST in xxxx on line xxx`

The codes seems to be working fine, but the notice is annoying and I expect notices are used for a reason.  How can I clear this notice?

Comment: BTW: PHP version is 5.2.17, host server is linux

Comment: By forcing a variable into HTTP_HOST, the notice clears, but notice still occurs with other functions that use '&' to pass by reference.  Apparently this is predicated and now issues a notice.  I'm not sure if this means passing by reference is no longer needed with function calls and security is no longer compromised in v.5.2.17+.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is deprecated;  use [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
$mail->setSMTPParams('*mail.xxxx.xxx*', 26, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 1,
    '*email-name*', '*email-password*');
```

Comment: @mjpsr11:  Are you running the script through a web server or as a CLI script?

Comment: @mjpsr11:  I would suggest `print_r`ing the variable `$_SERVER` to see what information is there.  Perhaps you can paste the output into your original question.

Comment: @Tom Cooper: response for HTTP_HOST is my url as expected.  The notice only occurs when running my script from a cron job.

Comment: @mjpsr11:  A cron job means it is not running through the web server then.  You'll have to supply that variable to the script some other way.

Comment: @Tom Cooper: well it worked for the past 2 years and now after a PHP version upgrade, I get this notice.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @mjpsr11:  What PHP version did you upgrade from?

Comment: @Tom Cooper: Not sure.  I can check with provider, but assume 5.2.16